# How can I associate a web application with a file format or mime type?

Tags: web-applications, mime-types

Is any way to make a web application the default handler for a specific file type/extension/mime type? That is, can I make my browser load a web application which can handle .blah files when I click on a .blah link?

Rationale: I'd like to be able to set up my web application for playing the game of go so it can open .sgf files without saving them to disk and re-uploading them or providing a url etc.

I figure this goes on stack overflow because it's fine to have to change web application to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is **not** possible.

This would require support by the different browsers and/or OS to map a mime-type/file extension to a web application (instead of a desktop application).

This is not currently supported by any browser I know.

If you can setup the OS to open a URL then you may be able to do this (not possible in Windows).

Comment: Thank you for answering, your reply got me thinking differently about the problem.

Comment: this seems to be possible now as ive seen it done but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using the [`file_handlers`](https://web.dev/file-handling/) property in a [web app manifest](https://web.dev/add-manifest/).

As of Chrome version 99 this feature is hidden behind a flag, to use it launch Chrome with the command line flag `--enable-features=FileHandlingAPI`, or go to chrome://flags/#file-handling-api and enable it.

[Here's a demo](https://morning-bubbly-chauffeur.glitch.me/) with [source code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/morning-bubbly-chauffeur).